# Regex PHP to match ALL this-> (this|is|this is) including "this is" as a match from a string

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string:

`"Hello, this is my string, exclude thisis!"`

I want a regex to match `this`, `is` and `this is` but NOT `thisis`.

So far i tried `(?i)\b(this|is|this is)\b`

but it only matches `"this"` and `"is"`.

What do i miss and i don't get also `"this is"`?

Comment: Try `(this is|this|is)` The larger super set strings should come first in the alternation list. You can add assertions to cover the adjacent problem `(this is|this(?!is)|(?<!this)is)`

Comment: This is going to be "tags" from from user input and i can not change the order of the inputs. :/

Comment: `(?i)\b(this is|this|is)\b`: sort them by length. (the first always wins.)

Comment: `i can not change the order of the inputs` - But you can sort it first. The reality is if you _can't_ put the superset's first, regex will not work.

Comment: (?i)\b(this is|this|is)\b is not maching "this" and "is", (this is|this(?!is)|(?<!this)is) is not matching "this". Changing the order of the inputs is what i will do as a last resort. But thanks a lot so far.

Comment: @Google: https://regex101.com/r/Z3wH1s/1

Comment: Google it *(sorry I can't help myself)*.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte thanks, well if this is the only way to go, ill take it :)

Comment: `(?i)\b(this is|this|is)\b is not maching "this" and "is",` https://regex101.com/r/Z3wH1s/3 `(this is|this(?!is)|(?<!this)is) is not matching "this".` https://regex101.com/r/Z3wH1s/2